# I'm making a guitar stand and need a maximum dowel weight

Tags: dowel

I'm making a wall hanging guitar stand, and I need a strong dowel to hold the V shaped head to the block that I'm going to mount in the wall. The dimensions of the head are 
L:5 3/16" 
W:3 11/16"
H:1/2"

I was thinking of using a 3" x 3/16" dowel but I don't know if that will support the 10-20 pounds it needs too. I already looked at a post about how much weight a dowel can hold and it didn't help me much. Help please?

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  IT would be helpful to know how long the dowel will be between supports.  Also, if you have a sketch of what you want to build, please add it. My initial reaction is that a 5/*' or 3/4" should be plenty strong enough of a span of  1' +/-

Comment: I started to write an answer, but it only revealed more questions. How are you planning on attaching the dowels to the block that will be mounted on the wall? Are you getting dowels of a specific kind of wood? Or just buying mystery wood dowels from the hardware store? (The latter are perfectly serviceable, but then I'd consider building in more margin for strength, erring on the side of a wider dowel.)

Comment: Either way, I agree with @Ashlar that 3/16" seems small. Personally, I wouldn't go any lower than 3/8" diameter dowel for this, and I'd feel a lot better at 1/2", or even 5/8" or 3/4" as Ashlar said.

Comment: @CharlieKilian I changed my mind and am going to use a 1/2" dowel. I'm going to drill a 1/2" inch hole into the block and then glue the dowel in and drill holes in the 4 corners for screws. And yeah, I was gonna use "mystery dowels" from the hardware store lol. But thank you.

Comment: also a hardwood dowel will be stronger